# Form of availability of data

Tags: r, matrix, vector, package, dataset

In R, I am doing some practice of regression in R datasets. In the **MASS** package in R, there is a dataset named **accdeaths**, data of accidental deaths in the US in 1973-1978. I am not understanding what is the form of availability of the data, i.e. when I write **accdeaths** the data appears in the form of 6*12 grid, which is not a matrix. It is giving FALSE on both is.vector(accdeaths) and is.matrix(accdeaths). I want to get it in matrix form so that I can regress on based on columns and rows, whichever way I want. How do I convert that into a matrix?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a time series object. It would be best to convert it to a data frame for regression analysis.

If you want a matrix, do:

```r
my_matrix <- t(matrix((MASS::accdeaths), nrow = 12))
```

And to make that a data frame, do:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(my_matrix)
names(df) <- month.abb
df$Year <- 1973:1978
df <- df[,c(13, 1:12)]
df
#>   Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
#> 1 1973 9007 8106 8928 9137 10017 10826 11317 10744 9713 9938 9161 8927
#> 2 1974 7750 6981 8038 8422  8714  9512 10120  9823 8743 9129 8710 8680
#> 3 1975 8162 7306 8124 7870  9387  9556 10093  9620 8285 8466 8160 8034
#> 4 1976 7717 7461 7767 7925  8623  8945 10078  9179 8037 8488 7874 8647
#> 5 1977 7792 6957 7726 8106  8890  9299 10625  9302 8314 8850 8265 8796
#> 6 1978 7836 6892 7791 8192  9115  9434 10484  9827 9110 9070 8633 9240
```

Answer (score 1):

It is time series, as you can see below

```
> require(MASS)
> class(accdeaths)
[1] "ts"
```

If you want it as a matrix, you can try

```
accdeathsM <- matrix(accdeaths,ncol = 12, byrow = T)
```